# How would I rewrite all files with a certain extension?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to rewrite all files that end in .wtf with a line of code, but I don't know how to go about doing this.

I know you can rewrite a file using the >> command but I want to use it so I can overwrite a file that can be in many different places(Ex: text.wtf has the words hey in it and is in the program files folder and I want to replace hey with yeh but not change its location.  txet.wtf has the words get in it and is in the user1 folder and I also want get replaced with yeh but nit change its location)

Comment: To write rather than append, use `>` instead of `>>` (at least, on *nix/Mac)

Answer (score 1):

$ find . -iname '*.wtf'  -exec sh -c 'echo -n found: {}\ ; mv "{}" "`read -p "rename to what?: " input; echo $input.wtf`"'  \;

Not perfect because you will have to input the folders where the files were found too, not only the new file names. But it's usable. After all, there is the middle mouse button...

Answer (score 0):

Ярослав put it in UNIX

This is for DOS/Windows CLI:

to find a specific file in any on your C drive then overwrite it with the string "yeh":

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`DIR /a /s /b "c:\" ^| FIND "text.wtf"`) DO (
ECHO yeh>"%%F"
)
```

/a allows for all types of files

/s specifies all subdirectories

/b cuts down the information to strictly output the FQFN